# Google Earth Engine (gee) reduceResolution() tile size error

Tags: resampling, reducers, google-earth-engine, reprojection-error

I'm trying to rescale an image (30 to 100m spatial resolution) using reduceResoluton().reproject() functions in Google Earth Engine (GEE). What I wanted is calculating the mean values of the 30 m image into the new 100 m resolution image.
I have tried the following

```
var img_100 = img_30.reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      bestEffort: true,
      maxPixels: 10,
    })
    .reproject({
      crs: 'EPSG:4326',
      scale: 100
    });
```

I have used one Landsat scene and it prompt the tile error "Tile error: Output of image computation is too large ":
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DI7C.jpg)
Am I missing something? Is there another way of performing this task?
Thank you all very much

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to export as an Asset, and then import the image again.
Not sure if this is the best practice but worked out fine.
If someone has an alternative please let us know.
Thanks!

```
Export.image.toAsset({
  image: img_100,
  description:'img_100',
  scale:100
```